# NuGet Package Manager not seeing one package as already updated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I want to know how I can debug a NuGet package not properly showing as updated. In my specific case the package for **jQuery.Validation** is (the only one left) in the "Update" list, but hitting the update button does nothing. Here's the dialog for Managing NuGet Packages for my solution:

[image: Manage NuGet Packages dialog]

Hitting the "Update" button will give an additional popup:

[image: dialog for updating the package]

As you can see everything seems slightly grayed out (what does that mean?). Hitting "Ok" just brings me back to the other dialog.

The main problem is that I don't know how to debug this sort of problem. I've tried doing the following:

- Opening the Package Manager Console to see if it logs any trouble. No dice.
- Checking the `jquery.validate.min.js` file, which mentions version *1.13.1*, which is in fact the one mentioned in the dialog as the newest version.
- Checking the `packages.config` file, which also mentions my solution includes version *1.13.1*.
- Restarting Visual Studio. No dice.
- Remove the package. Re-add the package. No dice (not even after restarting Visual Studio again).

**Is this just a bug in the Package Manager or the package? How can I further debug the root cause of this problem?**

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, have updated the product as well as all extensions (including the NuGet package manager). The solution was originally based on an MVC 2 template, and has been updated for each major MVC release (currently up to MVC 5). Only this particular package is giving trouble, I've succesfully updated 10+ other packages just before this one.

Comment: FWIW, [1.13.1 is also the latest version](http://jqueryvalidation.org)

Comment: Since I have had the same issue with other, completely unrelated packages, I assume it's a bug in the package manager.

Comment: @Jeroen Since there is a new package manager due out soon (with a host of changes to NuGet itself, as well), it may be a moot point. If you're adventurous, you could try digging into the code for the VS extension: https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: @Jeroen - Is there an old version of jQuery.Validation in your packages directory? If there is and it is not used by any projects I would try removing it from the packages directory to see if it fixes the update shown in the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you have an old NuGet package left in the packages directory.

When managing packages for the solution the NuGet dialog will show updates for all packages that are in the packages directory even if they are not installed into any projects. If you manage the packages for the project on its own the NuGet dialog would not show any package updates as being available.

So the workaround is to remove the unwanted NuGet package from the packages directory.

Comment: Where is this packages directory? I dont have any package directory in Project/Solution

Comment: This would be the packages directory inside your solution. This answer is for older Visual Studio versions so might not apply in your situation.